# Previous versions of Xcode... advertised anywhere?

Tags: iphone, xcode

People seem to be coming up with links to download previous versions of Xcode (which I used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385)). Is there a page on apple.com that advertises these, or is this just secret knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

[Newest Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/whats-new.html)

old versions from old site (under developer tools) (requires login/registration):
[long link](https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?appIdKey=D635F5C417E087A3B9864DAC5D25920C4E9442C9339FA9277951628F0291F620&path=/%2Fiphone%2FurlRedirect.action%3FfullURL%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fconnect.apple.com%252Fcgi-bin%252FWebObjects%252Fregister.woa%252F13%252Fwa%252Fdefault%253Fmode%253Dregister%2526userAction%253Dlogin%2526successURL%253Dhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fconnect.apple.com%25252Fcgi-bin%25252FWebObjects%25252FMemberSite.woa%25252Fwa%25252Flogin%25253Faction%25253Ddownloads)

EDIT: [Here](http://meandmark.com/blog/2009/10/downloading-older-versions-of-xcode/)'s a fun article that shows you how to do it as well

Answer (score 0):

URL: <http://connect.apple.com>; login; click "Downloads", "Developer Tools".