# Base SDK Missing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get “Base SDK missing”, can't see other SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdk)

I just upgraded my xcode directly from the website i.e. I downloaded the new version of xcode which came with ios4 - yet when I finished installing everything including the SDK it now says base sdk missing?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have du update your app, too.

in `Groups & Files`klick on `Targets` and doubleclick you application.
then select your configuration and search for `Base SDK` under the `Architectures` section. select the 4.0 there

Comment: Please don't tell me I have to setup up the keychains etc with the device again?