# Install Xcode 3.2.4, get "Base SDK Missing"

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

When you update Xcode to 3.2.4, your previously working Xcode iOS project gives you the message "Base SDK Missing". Something like this:

[image: Ruh-roh!]

What gives? How to fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks)

Comment: Hi Brad. I wrote that other post. Since this is confusing for many, and the 3.2.3 switchover had some other confusing wrinkles, I figured a Q/A specific to 3.2.4 might be helpful.

Comment: Seems pretty ridiculous to post the same question and answer time after time, just replacing the version number. Feels like rep fishing to me.

Comment: @Jakob: jeez, do a diff.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## The Problem

iOS SDK 4.0 is gone in this release, replaced by iOS SDK 4.1. Details in "The Explanation" below. (NB: this repeats some information in my [previous Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385) regarding 3.2.3).

## The Fix

To fix this specific problem, you need to reset the Base SDK for your target(s), etc. You can either do that for the entire project (most folks), or for each target and/or configuration which applies. Rarely, you might need to do both.

### Edit Project Settings

1. Load your project
2. From the menu, select Project > Edit Project Settings...
3. Click the "Build" tab.
4. Under "Configurations" select "All Configurations".
5. Go to the **Change Base SDK** section below.

### Edit Specific Target/Configuration Settings

1. Load your project
2. From the menu, select Project > Active Target > "YourTarget"
3. From the menu, select Project > Edit Active Target "YourTarget"
4. Click the "Build" tab.
5. Under "Configurations" select "All Configurations", or the Configuration you want.
6. Go to the **Change Base SDK** section below.

### Change Base SDK

1. Under Architecture > Base SDK, choose one of the available device
   options: iOS Device 3.2 or iOS Device 4.1. If you are iPhone-only, 4.1 is the way to go.
2. If you want to target previous iOS versions, then in that same
   window, under Deployment > iPhone OS Deployment Target, select the
   lowest version you want to support. Note that support for 2.x versions
   through the app store is deprecated.

## The Explanation

iOS SDK 4.0 is gone in this release, replaced by iOS SDK 4.1. This is very similar with what happened with the 3.2.3 upgrade, which I covered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385). You can still use 3.2.4 to target iOS versions down to 3.0, but AFAIK, you must compile against the 4.1 SDK with Xcode 3.2.4. If this statement confuses you, study the following sentence closely:

*The iOS SDK you compile against -- the "Base SDK" -- does not downward limit what iOS versions you can support.*

In fact, there are two different settings, cf. **Change Base SDK** above. If you remain confused, take heart, and read my [detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385) on the previous switchover, which is itself chockablock with links to good stuff.

Comment: Thanks for bringing some much-needed clarity to a frustrating problem. I’ve just learned something I’ll take with me every time I use Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems for 3.2.5 and followed the same instructions.  It didn't work for me, but I noticed that new projects would work properly.  When I grepped ShareKit.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj, I noticed that there were still stray references to iphoneos4.0 in the file for SDKROOT param even after changing it in xcode.  Manually editing this file and changing all references of SDKROOT to iphoneos fixed the problem.  Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For all older projects, select the main window, select Option-Cmd-E, choose build and "latest ios...".

Close the build window.

In the main window, option-click the dropdown for Base SDK and you should see the latest build available.

It's still a pita, but it's easier than navigating, closing windows, etc....

If anyone knows a better method, I'd be happy to hear it...