# App runs on simulator but not on device

Tags: xcode, device, code-signing

Every time I put my app to run on my device I receive this error:

```
[BEROR]CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 
'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.3'
```

But when i run it on the simulator, no problems or anything.
Does anyone have a suggestion of what may be causing this difference?
Thanks.

Comment: NEW PROBLEM:I FOLLOWED THE INSTRUCTIONS ON THE LINK OF THE ANSWER:

/Users/fgringo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GuessTheBalls-cmqhhylrtlhqjoalguqkqvuxgsgv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GuessTheBalls.app: object file format invalid or unsuitable
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

IS IT THE SAME?

Answer (score 1):

In order to deploy to a device you need a signing key and certificate. Apple will sign your cert request when you pay for your apple iphone developer license.

You then tell your xcode project to sign with your signing key before deploying to your iphone/ipod

This feels like a duplicate of: [Xcode 'CodeSign error: code signing is required'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804191/xcode-codesign-error-code-signing-is-required)

Comment: well, i am a payed developer. i tried deleting all my provisioning stuff and downloading it again, but no luck. Have more ideas?