# base sdk missing

Tags: iphone

HI i downloaded a project and try to build its showing error

[BEROR]error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos3.1.2'

So It means i do not have ios sdk 3.1.2

My IOS SDK is 4.3

So i tought i need to download IOS SDK 3 for my xcode. in order to build the application.

in developer.apple i found ios sdk 4.3 only.

If you found any link for iOS sdks 3.12 please post

@All

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project -> Edit Project Settings, and then Build tab. Have a look at the Base SDK, if it's set to 3.1.2 you should set it to latest iOS.

Comment: yeap its working....... but after running i got another error   [BEROR]Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

Comment: do i need to change any thing in plist

Comment: Have a look at [Xcode 'CodeSign error: code signing is required'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804191/xcode-codesign-error-code-signing-is-required) if this helps. Does the project build for the simulator?

Comment: oops.......thanks nick weaver  i changed it to simulator.... thanks working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use iOS 3.1.2 with the new xCode4 or after upgrading iOS.  You may always define the minimum target iOS lower.

Also, when I plug in my iPhone which is still on 4.1, I can change the setting in "EDIT SCHEME" on the top right to my iPhone 4.1 (overriding 4.3) and also select the simulator on 4.1, 4.2 or 4.3

So no need to set the baseSDK to 3.1.2 or anything low.