# code signing is required for iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, code-signing

I get this error when I try to test with my device.

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 6.1'

XCode ver 4.6.2

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you have an Apple Developer Account?

Comment: Are you running it on device or in simulator?

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch09.html#_running_on_a_device

Comment: Please at least put some minimum effort to search for an answer before posting such a question. SO even showed you several existing questions that already answered your question before you submitted yours.

Answer (score 2):

Right now in `Build Settings`, it probably looks like this
[image]

You have to code sign an app to test it, so change it so it looks like this
[image]

Note that to be able to test on a device, you must be a registered Apple Developer (Payed the $99), and have your device set up for development with your provisioning profile installed.

**EDIT**

Make sure in Organizer->Devices, your phone is set up for development and has your iOS team provisioning profile installed. Also, make sure that your device is set up to be used with your provisioning profile in the provisioning portal. If nothing else works, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804275/1702077) answer.

Comment: You got to it moments before me :P

Comment: I have apple developer account.
It's only happen when i try with my device, on simulator is ok.
And ur advice didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Select your project>Project Name>Build Settings>Code Signing>"Code Signing Identity" now fill the fields with your code signing profiles.