Xcode 15 - Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
While building app on device I get an error "CodeSign failed with error", but after restart mac I can build maybe twice on device successfully and then I get an error again. I have tried a lot of solutions, but none of them works for me.

Tried to change CodeSign in Build Setting to iOS Development and etc
Clean build and restart XCode
Relogin in Xcode


Can you add the exact error message? Usually there is more information in the build log

@Deitsch /Users/ekaterinapolupanova/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rolf-codajgytykimlxgzhpkkxzzmwfwy/Build/Products/Debug Development-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex: replacing existing signature
Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "(null)"
/Users/ekaterinapolupanova/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rolf-codajgytykimlxgzhpkkxzzmwfwy/Build/Products/Debug Development-iphoneos/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex: errSecInternalComponent
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

This Answer may help You https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804191/xcode-codesign-error-code-signing-is-required
