# how to fix old xcode installations on mac

Tags: xcode, macos

I had xcode 3.2.something. and iwth ios sdks 3.0-3.1-....4.1 and 2 iphone simulator sdks.

Now i installed xcode 4.0 with ios sdk 4.3 something like that.

Now all my previous applications cannot be launched nor on device nor on simulator because there's not a single old sdk available.

so next i reinserted the original cds containing macosx and xcode and reinstalled the first xcode i used, but now there's not one ios sdk available at all.

i've been surfing the net for hours now, andi  have a couple of questions:
1)have i had to uninstall the xcode 3.2.x before installing xcode 4?
2)how to uninstall applications on mac??? just to make sure that the answer i've found is the correct one.
3)how can erase the traces of all previous xcodes and their sdks in order to install the original one, now that i learned how to install different xcode versions side by side.
4) now what do you think i should to recover? do i have to back up everything and reinstall mac from the beginning?

thank you

Comment: what about setting different base sdk value for your app ? Have a look on [Install Xcode 3.2.4, get “Base SDK Missing”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677487/install-xcode-3-2-4-get-base-sdk-missing)

Answer (score 2):

So, your questions:

*1. Have I got to uninstall XCode 3.2 before installing XCode 4?* - No, you don't, but the XCode installer will overwrite your old copy by default. When installing the newer version of XCode and the iOS SDK you must specify a **different** install directory (eg, create a new folder in the root of your drive called 'Developer 4' for XCode 4.

*2. How can I uninstall XCode?* - Normally on a mac you would just drag your application to the trash, but it's a little more complicated with XCode. Refer to the instructions at this link: http://pushkararora.com/how-to/how-to-uninstall-xcode-completely/

*3. How can I erase all traces of all previous XCodes?* - see the answer above for question 2 :)

You can obtain old versions of the SDK from various unofficial online sources if you need to roll back to iOS 3 SDKs. However, it may not be all that much work to move your apps over to the 4.x SDKs.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm reading the recommended link; and i'm using software update in mac, maybe it will patch the xcode like the first time i started working

Comment: i erased everything xcode using the link you provided and then installed the xcode from the mac cd. and updated on the internet. Still all i got was a new sdk in xcode concerned mac 10.6 so i have now 3 ios sdks targetting mac platforms not iphoneos. So what can i do now? should i format? and start all over again?
i need the ios 3 sdks because i don't want to lose compatibility iwth them so i need to build targetting them to know and test.

Answer (score 0):

ok it turned out that at the beginning i was using xcode 3.2.4 with ios sdk 4.1 
The xcode that comes with mac osx only targets mac sdk. No iphone support

So i got xcode 3.2.4 setup from a backup (you can find it online) and installed and this should work
And now i have 3.2.5 using sdk 4.2 and targetting all till 3.0
and also xcode 4.0.2