# XCode 3.2.5 Base SDK missing, can only compile for simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk

I used this answer: [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks) and it doesn't work.  I still have "Base SDK Missing" and I can only choose simulators to compile for.  I'm ready to device test but there's no iPhone in the Active Executable list.

I just updated to the newest 4.2 and 3.2.5 XCode

Comment: Have you made sure to select **Latest iOS** for both your Xcode project and your build targets?

Comment: I shut down in frustration, came back just now, and the option was there.  Maybe I just needed a restart?

Comment: This just happened to me too, restarted and still was an issue, read this http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/base-sdk-and-iphone-os-deployment-target-developing-apps-with-the-4-x-sdk-deploying-to-3-x-devices.html and started to mess around with the settings, after setting the target os 3-4 times it magically worked again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base-SDK can be set for the project and for the targets. please check both places.

Comment: It just started working by itself after a restart.  Voted up and checked answer anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did to fix this problem:

In my project settings (the blue icon at the top of the Groups and Files pane) in the General tab, I set "Base SDK for All Configurations" to "Latest iOS"

In the build tab, I searched for "SDK" and set "Base SDK" to "Latest iOS"

In the settings for my target (The "A" icon under the "Targets" icon in Groups and Files) I searched in the Build tab for "SDK" and set it to "Latest iOS".

Restarted Xcode and it's happy days.

Answer (score 1):

The same as the xcode 3.2.4 but just restart the project.
When you change the base sdk the xcode can't refurbish the state.