# Base SDK Missing - permanent solution?

Tags: iphone, xcode

This fantastic post helps clarify how to fix this problem for a single project.

> [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks)

However, it seems I have to do this little dance for **every** project with sample code I download. I didn't mind for the first two or three times but it's now getting hugely repetitive and boring.

Isn't there a permanent way of resolving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

But, if you choose "Latest iOS SDK" and save the project, at least you won't have to do it ever again for that particular project.

For Apple's sample code, hope they update their projects -- or, better yet, file bugs asking them to fix them at http://bugreport.apple.com/ -- so you don't have to fix them.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer. Knowing that there isn't an easier way makes it a bit more bearable!