# iPhone 3.2 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I'm working with a legacy app with a deployment target of 3.0. I have a crash being reported on iOS 3.1.3 for iPhone. In xcode 4 the only 3.x simulator I see listed is **iPad** 3.2

How do I test iOS 3.1.3 for iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy a used iPhone or iPod Touch that has 3.1.3 installed and don't update the iOS on it.  I have a 3G with 313, no cell service and just use it for testing on wifi.  This is also useful to see check what the performance is like on a slower phone.

However, many 3.1.3 crashes are caused by using a 4.0 API call or object that is only in 4.0.  You can find those problems on the 3.2 simulator.

Comment: It turns out you can run on an iOS 3.1.3 device from Xcode 4, but you can't use the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

See [Install xCode 3.2.3 w/ iPhone SDK 4, get "Base SDK missing", can't see other SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdks) for an extended discussion of this topic. Also, links to older Xcode and iOS SDK versions can be found at http://chris-fletcher.com/2010/08/28/howto-install-iphone-sdk-2-0-3-1-for-xcode-3-2/.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible actually with Xcode4. If you can get old version of Xcode3.1 with iOS SDK 3.1 and install it side by side with Xcode4 then it may be possible.

Comment: Yes, I have three Xcode/iOS IDEs installed (Xcode3/iOS3, Xcode3/iOS4 and Xcode4/iOS4) and they all play well together.