# how to edit project settings in xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2, project-settings

This sounds dumb but i want to edit my project settings and change my delevelper profile of a project which in xcode 3.2 was project>>edit active targets/ edit project settings

but cant find this on xcode 4.2 beta version :(

Does anyone know how to.

thnx alot in advance.

Comment: did you know: Quote from Apple page: "Xcode 4.2 Developer Preview, iOS 5 beta, iTunes 10.5 beta, iWork for iOS beta, and Apple TV Software beta are pre-release software and are considered Apple Confidential Information and are subject to the terms of your iOS Developer Program License Agreement. Unauthorized distribution or disclosure of Apple Confidential Information is prohibited." Just ask in the ADC/ADF ps it is also in the transition docs...

Comment: i am a License developer and did download it from my develoiper account only..

Comment: Yes, but this is not the issue, we are just not allowed to talk about it here. I also had to ask couple of questions in ADF.. Anyway,  Sherman Lo's answer is applicable here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As previously mentioned I can't talk about Xcode 4.2, however in Xcode 4.1 to change your provisioning profile you would do this:

- Select the Project navigator using folder icon on the left of the navigator sidebar
- Select the Project, which will be at the top of that view.
- The project configuration will appear in the main editor panel, to edit the provisioning profile select "Build Settings" at the top and search for provisioning to pull up the