# Base SDK Missing, apple fix does not fly -> XCode Base SDK popup only shows iphoneos, but I am expecting to see Latest IOS (...)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

When I downloaded the UICatalog demo and clicked on UICatalog.xcodeproj file in finder, I got the BASE SDK missing/error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos'

This apple fix at 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1701/_index.html

[image]says I should set the Base SDK to Latest IOS(Currentlyset to iOS 4.2), but I only get iphoneos as a possible option.

[image]
I found this other link

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

that says the I should see the SDKs in the /Developer/SDKs directory, but this is what I have:

```
ray:/Developer/SDKs> ls
MacOSX10.4u.sdk MacOSX10.5.sdk  MacOSX10.6.sdk
ray:/Developer/SDKs> cd ..
ray:/Developer> ls Platforms/
MacOSX.platform
```

I have recently downloaded. XCode.Version 4.6.3 (4H1503)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That screenshot does not look like 4.6.3. Also, it looks like a Mac app?

Comment: Yes, David that confused me.  After, I downloaded the project. I double clicked on the UICatalog.xcodeproj file in finder and that is what came up.  Maybe I'm importing the project incorrectly.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the right version of Xcode? The screenshots you posted look like you're running Xcode 3.

Comment: Yes it was the wrong version.  See my answer for how I got there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Yes this happens all the time when downloading sample code. Don't stress. You can click on validate settings in newer versions of xcode, and in older ones you can manually update it under your architectures settings but it may take some fiddling.

[image]

Comment: Saw this as well which might help [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161385/install-xcode-3-2-3-w-iphone-sdk-4-get-base-sdk-missing-cant-see-other-sdk?rq=1)

Comment: I also saw the link you mentioned above.  However, as I show in the screen dumps above, I don't see the popup options they say I am supposed to get.

Comment: Oh if you click on your project name the same way that you did before to get the project settings then it will be a big round button at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Mines xcode 4.6.2 but the one in your screen shot looks like 3.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of other answers/comments I noticed I was not in the right version of XCode.

When I double clicked on the project file (UICatalog.xcodeproj) in finder, it opened an older version of xcode by default (version 3.2.6).  To fix the problem, I right clicked on the xcodeproj file then "open with" to find that there were two versions of xcode available.  After I selected the newest version of xcode.app (version 4.6.3), everything built fine.